# K distinct hash functions

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, hash, hash-function

I have a list of items , for example ["Alice","Bob","Alice","John"] and I want to generate k hash functions such that :

h1("Alice") = val1

h2("Alice")  = val2

...

hk("Alice") = val3

I tried using MD5 algorithm in Python2.X for hashing but it will give the same value for the same string.

Comment: What is your goal exactly ? what output do you want based on what input ? How do you understand hash function and why do you to use it , for what purpose ?

Answer (score 1):

the purpose of a `hash`-function **is** to generate the same hash for the same input... . You can add a salt-value before hashing though:

```
string[] salt = {"salt1" , "salt2" , ...}

hash(k , s):
    return hash(s + salt[k])
```